# Using Macros with C++ and UnitTest++

Tags: c++, unittest++

I am working on a large C++ project, for safety critical aerospace software, we have about 50 developers working on the project, so of course it is huge, we are using C++ on Red Hat Linux with a little bit of Java and Python, and also small parts of the system are hosted on IBM AIX Unix and Windows.

I recently was hired into this project and found that UnitTest++ was being used to do unit tests. One thing that has me confused is how UnitTest++ is working with macros. It is using a macro to define a derived class and then a call to the macro calls a base class method. It is very unusual, I tried to reproduce the same thing in a small example C++ program but was not able to get it to work. Note the source code for the example program. I am not able to post the specific code in our project due to an NDA.

There should be a way to get this to work, it is working in our unit tests using UnitTest++

```
// macro2.cpp

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class TestBaseClass
{
    public:

    // class constructor
    TestBaseClass() : num1(3), num2(8)
    {
        cout << "Object Created" << endl;
    }

    // class properties
    int num1;
    int num2;

    // class method
    void testMethod()
    {
        cout << "testMethod() called" << endl;
    }

    // class destructor
    ~TestBaseClass()
    {
        cout << "Object Destroyed" << endl;
    }

};


#define TEST_MACRO(TestBaseClass) \
    class TestDerivedClass : public TestBaseClass \
    { \
        public: \
        TestDerivedClass() { num1 = 10; } \ 
    }; \

int main() 
{

    // call macro base class method
    TEST_MACRO(TestBaseClass)
    {
        testMethod();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm stating the already-obvious, but the call ```testMethod()``` here falls outside the class definition of TestDerivedClass. Essentially, you're looking for a way to expose testMethod within the scope below the macro (and hence, outside the class), is this correct?

Comment: Yes, the testMethod() is public in the base class, this is an example of how the code is working in UnitTest++, I have not been able to figure out how it is able to call the base class method without creating an object in the brackets for the macro call, the only way I could get it to work was by creating a TestDerivedClass object.

Comment: This works:  // call macro base class method
 TEST_MACRO(TestBaseClass)
 {
  TestDerivedClass test;
  test.testMethod();
 } but  // call macro base class method
 TEST_MACRO(TestBaseClass)
 {
  testMethod();
 } does not work, but appears to work in UnitTest++ for some reason

Comment: Joint Strike Fighter (JSF) C++ Guide recommends to not use macros, maybe this is one of the reasons why.

Comment: @MichaelG.Workman Preprocessor macros and templates are the two metalanguage features of C++. Some would say their design is crude by today's standards, but they do allow to automate a lot of unnecessary coding. It is good advice to avoid macros altogether in certain contexts, but it would be a grave error to generalize to every situation.

Having said that, my reply as well as your comment probably shouldn't be here, i.e. they do not attempt to clarify to the question or help answer it. We should probably refrain from further discussion here...

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: not 100% sure of how UnitTest++ does it, but Boost unit testing seems to be doing the same thing, and I cannot think of any other this can be done.

The solution is to end the TEST_MACRO with a method signature within the class `TestDerivedClass`, so that the scope (`{ //call to things within TestDerivedClass}`) that follows serves as an implementation to that method.

Since you cannot declare a class within a function scope, you'll also need to issue the call to this method via some other structure (i.e. Boost unit testing generates the main method via macros as well)

Here is a working example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class TestBaseClass
{
public:

    // class constructor
    TestBaseClass() : num1(3), num2(8)
    {
        cout << "Object Created" << endl;
    }

    // class properties
    int num1;
    int num2;

    // class method
    void testMethod()
    {
        cout << "testMethod() called" << endl;
    }

    // class destructor
    ~TestBaseClass()
    {
        cout << "Object Destroyed" << endl;
    }

};


#define TEST_MACRO(TestBaseClass) \
class TestDerivedClass : public TestBaseClass \
{ \
    public: \
    TestDerivedClass() { num1 = 10; } \
    void testMethodInternal(); \
}; \
   \
void TestDerivedClass::testMethodInternal()

// call macro base class method
TEST_MACRO(TestBaseClass)
{
    testMethod();
}

int main()
{
    TestDerivedClass inst;
    inst.testMethodInternal();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I think I know exactly what you are saying, I did notice there was a few method definitions outside of the scope of the class in the macro definition, which had me a bit confused, but I will try it.

Comment: No, sorry, still not able to get it to work, going to move onto something new now.